# Find and delete subString in a String with delimiters (start: 55555, end: \n)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this String:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim adminim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat 55555 Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur.
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

In this string, there are three paragraphs, I need to find this subString: `"55555"` and delete from there to the next newline (end of the line). How could you do this?

Comment: I do not know how to use the features to look for a subString and delete up to end of line

Comment: with such text formatting, it is not clearly where paragraphs are.

Comment: now you can see this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may choose the needed part of the whole string and split it by `\n`. Then change the paragraph that needs to be corrected.

```
String[] strings = string.split("\n");
strings[1] = strings[1].substring(0, strings[1].indexOf("55555"));
```

Comment: yes but I need the part between "5555" and next "\n", not the front of "5555", if the String have 15 "\n"... How could selecct the "\n" that is behind "5555"????

Comment: Use `strings[1].split("5+\\s*")[1]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, `strings[1].split("5+\\s*")[0] + "."`?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
String strings = string.substring(string.indexOf("55555"), string.indexOf("\n"));
```

Comment: it throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: because `"\n"` may be found before `"55555"`

Comment: You should use [`String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made a program that will hopefully solve your problem. Note that the program takes multi-line input, so you have to enter a comma (**,**) to end the input. It'll first take the main string as input and then ask for the word to remove from it. It's a simple program: doesn't use the **substring()** function or other techniques as you are not acquainted with.

```
class ProgramTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String str1="", str2="", a="", w="", mystr="";

        System.out.println("Enter your string. Enter ',' to terminate input.");

        while(!(a=sc.nextLine()).equals(","))
            str1 += a+"\n";

        System.out.println("Enter word to remove");

        str2 = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
            if(str1.charAt(i)!=' '){
                w+=str1.charAt(i);
            }
            else{
                if(!(w.equals(str2)))
                mystr += w+" ";
                w="";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("String after removing "+str2+" is \n"+mystr);
    }
}
```